# How to display app API documentation by using springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, springdoc

I read this https://springdoc.org/demos.html to use springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui. As documentation said I just added `springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui` library to my app: `implementation('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.2.26')`

Additionally, I customized path to API in application.yml:

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html
```

When I start app, and go to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html, it redirects me to http://localhost:8080/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config. In that page, I got an error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Jan 20 05:16:10 UTC 2020
[7192d9dc] There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No matching handler
```

Question is: Should I add additional configurations to my app to show API documentation?

PS: I use spring.boot 2.2.2:RELEASE

Comment: However, I am able to get the documentation from http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs
which gives me the json file.

Comment: Any solution for this problem? I´m having the same issue with spring-boot 2.6.0.

Answer (score 3):

By default, you just need to add the dependency of the springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.32</version>
   </dependency>
```

You can have a look at the demos code:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos.git

You can check you classpath, and try to run the application from outside the IDE.
Make sure you have the correct settings of your IDE depending on your build Tools:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/361

Also, please check if you are using @EnableWebFlux.

As stated in the Spring Boot reference documentation, when you use @EnableWebFlux, you tell Spring Boot that you wish to take full control over the WebFlux configuration and disable all auto-configuration for this (including static resources):

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-webflux-auto-configuration

You have two solutions:

1. Remove @EnableWebFlux
2. If you really want take control of Bean creation and you want absolutely to use @EnableWebFlux, then you need to add an implementation of WebFluxConfigurer.

This has been discussed here:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/402

Comment: I am not running an app from IDE.

Comment: First validate that your application works inside an IDE then!

Comment: The link to the springdoc demos is broken