# Why predicate field in RouterFunctions.DefaultRouterFunction<T extends ServerResponse> class gets DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, springdoc

I am using `'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.2.28'` library to show swagger UI API documentation in my spring-boot app. http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html does not work, it returns:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Jan 24 11:31:02 UTC 2020
[b0282788] There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No matching handler
```

shortly this problem: [How to display app API documentation by using springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817409/how-to-display-app-api-documentation-by-using-springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui)

And I found a cause of that. `Predicate` field of `RouterFunctions.DefaultRouterFunction<T extends ServerResponse>` class sometimes gets `DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler` as an value of this object:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might be using @EnableWebFlux.
You description seems similar to this issue:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/402