# Unable to display Swagger/OpenApi docs when using SpringDoc webflux support

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-webflux, springdoc

I have a small Spring Boot micro-service that exposes its endpoint as reactive, using webflux.

When I run the application from IntelliJ, Gradle or from the cmd line with the SpringDoc webflux support:
`implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.4.4'`
and I go to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` I get a 500 error, the logs show:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest]`

and the root cause:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest.<init>()`

if I use `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`
I get a 404 instead of a 500.

However if I change the dependency to the non reactive SpringDoc module:
`implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.4.4'`

The docs are available, they just dont show return schema (I guess this is expected as the response is wrapped in a `Mono`).

[I have looked at this question, but it didnt help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817409/how-to-display-app-api-documentation-by-using-springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui)

I am using Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE, I have nothing "fancy" in the controller other than an autowired service class, the endpoint is simply annotated with the `GetMapping` and returns `Mono<T>`. and I have included the following dependencies:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.4.4'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project is using spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux.

You just need to remove spring-boot-starter-web from your dependencies.

Comment: Ah, that is a bit of an issue, as the Azure applications insight module doesnt support webflux currently (though it looks like they have a preview version available that does), as soon as I am able to upgrade the azure module I will revisit this.

Comment: Was able to confirm this will solve my issue on a different project .

Answer (score 4):

I have the restriction that I need to use Webflux via Servlet 3.1, even though it's not the pure Reactive solution but I can reuse some Spring security filter with Servlet.So, I cannot just remove spring-boot-starter-web as @brianbro suggested.

Therefore, I found a solution to make springdoc-openapi-ui be able to read Flux & Mono by adding WebFluxSupportConverter from springdoc-openapi-webflux-core as an extra converter. See the following code in Groovy.

```
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {

        ModelConverters.getInstance().addConverter(new WebFluxSupportConverter())

        return new OpenAPI()
            .components(new Components()
                .addSecuritySchemes("JWE", new SecurityScheme()
                    .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                    .scheme("bearer")
                    .bearerFormat("JWE")))
            .info(new Info()
                .title("Marketplace API")
                .version(apiVersion))
    }
```

So, you just need to include the libraries.

```
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.4.6'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-core:1.4.6'
```

Comment: thank you!. this worked for my problem. I was using sprng webflux and spring doc. Initially i tried to add the following dependencies in pom.xml file , springdoc-openapi-ui and springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core and it gave me an error. Later when changed to springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui and springdoc-openapi-webflux-core the application started fine and was able to access swagger.

Comment: It doesn't work now. There is need ....  WebFluxSupportConverter(ObjectMapperProvider objectMapperProvider). can someone explain. how can this be configured at the moment ? There is no default constructor there anymore

Answer (score 1):

For me in a kotlin spring boot project the problem was with an endpoint returning a Flux so it was throwing a graceful exception: `jackson BeanDescription.findJsonValueAccessor not found, this could lead to inaccurate result, please update jackson to 2.9+`
the approach from @Chayne P. S. solved my problem:

```
class OpenApiConfigiguration {

    @Bean
    fun configOpenAPI(): OpenAPI? {
        ModelConverters.getInstance().addConverter(WebFluxSupportConverter())
        return OpenAPI()
                .info(Info().title("API")
                        .description("WS restful API")
                        .version("v0.0.1")
                        .license(License().name("License of API")
                        .termsOfService("Terms of service"))
                .externalDocs(ExternalDocumentation()
                        .description("Docs")
                        .url(""))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question, but I still ran into the same issue today.

I forgot to change the `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` dependency to `springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui`.

After that it worked.